# Measure capacitance on a mutual capacitive touch sensor

Tags: capacitive, touchscreen, touch-panel, touch, measure

I interpret the mechanism of a mutual capacitive touch sensor like this:

There are 2 electrodes X and Y. To measure the difference in capacity, the X electrode is driven high (i.e 3.3 V) and the Y electrode gets measured in combination with a integrator circuit. I do not really understand which voltage we measure on the Y electrode. My basic understanding of an capacitor always was that we have + and -. We have for example 5 V at plus and 0 V on minus. I am assuming it has something to do with the changing capacitance when a finger is altering the electrostatic field, but I can not fully understand, why it is this way?